# Square matrices of same linear transformation has A and B similar

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices representing the same linear transformation, then $A$ and $B$ are similar.

---

Does this mean that $Av=\phi(v)=Bv$?

$Av=Bv=\lambda v$ implies they have the same eigenvalues is one observation.

$$P^{-1}AP=B$$ is what I am pretty sure I need however. $$AP=PB$$??

I don't see how I have the above - which is surely equivalent

Comment: What is your definition of *similar matrices*?

Comment: $P^{-1}AP=B$ means $A$ is similar to $B$

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not complete: what's asked is certainly that if $A$ and $B$ represent the  same linear mapping $\phi$ *in different bases*, the $A$ and $B$ are similar.

You have to use the change of basis formula: let $X$ be  the column vector of coordinates of $v$ in basis $\mathcal B$,  $X'$  its column vector of coordinates in basis $\mathcal B'$ and let $P$ the matrix with columns made up of the  coordinates of the vectors of $\mathcal B'$ calculated in the old basis $\mathcal B$. Then it is easy to check that $X=PX'$.

If $A$ is the matrix of $\phi$ in basis $\mathcal B$, you can fing its matrix $B$ in basis $\mathcal B'$ this way: $\phi(v)$ has column vector of coordinates $Y$ in basis $\mathcal B$, and $$Y=AX$$.

Thiss can be rewritten as $$PY'=A(PX')\enspace\text{whence}\enspace Y'=P^{-1}\bigl(A(PX')\bigr)= (P^{-1}AP)X'$$which proves $B=P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: Reading to understand now, thanks for your effort!